# Count number of groups in grouped data that fulfill a condition

Tags: r

I need to count how many Patients (my groups) fulfill a condition.

I have a large dataset and the last row always states yes or no (every patient has only yes or only no, but more of them), and now I need to know how many Patients are in the yes condition and how many patients are in the no condition.

I can only find results that count the conditions in a group, but not the groups by a condition.

The data looks like this:

```
structure(list(PATIENT.ID = c(210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 
210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 
210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 220909L, 
220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 
220909L, 220909L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 
221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 
221179L, 221179L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 
301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 
301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 303926L, 303926L, 303926L, 303926L
), Anycaffeina = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No"
)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And I want something like this: NO = N (here 1) and YES = N (here 4)

I now found a solution that worked with my dataset (much longer than the above and 81 columns, so maybe that's why @Yuriy Saraykin did not work with my original data?)

```
Anycaffeine[!duplicated(Anycaffeine$PATIENT.ID), ] 
count(z$Anycaffeina)
```

Comment: Please show a small example of your dataset, using `dput()`

Answer (score 1):

**tidyverse**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  count(Anycaffeina)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Anycaffeina     n
  <chr>       <int>
1 No              1
2 Yes             4
```

**base**

```
aggregate(.~Anycaffeina, data = unique(df), FUN = length)

  Anycaffeina PATIENT.ID
1          No          1
2         Yes          4
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(df) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  .[, .N, by = Anycaffeina] %>% 
  .[]

   Anycaffeina N
1:         Yes 4
2:          No 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I do not get the right results with the codes. For tidyverse and datable I get a count of all the yes and all the no (not the count of gouts that have yes and the groups that gave no). And for base I get an error messeage: > aggregate(.~Anycaffeina, data = unique(Anycaffeine), FUN = length)
Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate     .... do you know what my mistake ist?

Comment: please show a minimal example of data with an error and the desired result of calculations

Answer (score 0):

```r
z <- Anycaffeine[!duplicated(Anycaffeine$PATIENT.ID), ] 
count(z$Anycaffeina)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).